# Word list for World of Tanks

Tags: word-lists, games, listening

I would like to practice more Chinese listening and I like WoT, so it seems a good idea to watch WoT broadcasts at twitch. Did anybody have a WoT specific world list to prepare for it in advance? Or in general, a place where there are special world lists for various topics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't play this game, so I could not guarantee the correctness, I just search it for you.

Maps (http://tieba.baidu.com/p/2088067025?see_lz=1)

01_卡累利阿_karelia

02_马林诺夫卡_malinovka

03_坎帕尼亚_campania //已变为幼儿园专用图

04_锡墨尔斯多夫_himmelsdorf

05_普罗霍洛夫卡_prohorovka

06_安斯克_ensk

07_拉斯威利_lakeville

08_鲁别克_ruinberg

10_湖边的角逐_hills

11_穆勒万卡_murovanka

13_埃勒斯堡_erlenberg

14_齐格菲防线_siegfried_line

15_科马林_komarin//已不再出现

17_慕尼黑_munchen

18_海岸争霸_cliff

19_小镇争夺战_monastery

22_黑暗沼泽_slough//已不再出现

23_韦斯特菲尔德_westfeld

28_沙漠小镇_desert

29_埃尔哈罗夫_el_hallouf

31_阿拉曼机场_airfield

33_北欧峡湾_fjord

34_斯特拉斯福_redshire

35_荒蛮之地_steppes

36_费舍尔湾_fishing_bay

37_胜利之门_caucasus

38_极地冰原_mannerheim_line

39_雅尔塔_crimea

42_钢铁丛林_north_america

44_里夫奥克斯_north_america

45_洲际铁路_north_america

47_寂静海岸_canada_a

51_香格里拉_asia

bullets(http://tieba.baidu.com/p/2909880430)

HE，榴弹

AP,穿甲弹

APHE，穿甲榴弹

APC，被帽穿甲弹

APBC，风帽穿甲弹

APCBC，被帽风帽穿甲弹

APCR/HVAP，复合硬芯穿甲弹（字面翻译),次口径超速穿甲弹（常用名）。

APCNR，复合非硬芯穿甲弹（字面翻译），常用名未知，求高手指点。

APDS，次口径脱壳穿甲弹

APFSDS，次口径尾翼稳定脱壳穿甲弹

HEAT，破甲弹

HESH，碎甲弹

This may also help you. h.t.t.p://tieba.baidu.com/p/1857248247 (sorry I don't have enough reputations to post more links)